# PHP Register with MD5 password case shift

Tags: php, passwords, md5, case, shift

I'm pretty good with php, but my MySQL skills are still lacking.

I have this script, but don't know how to make a form with it, and don't know how to do a couple other things (mentioned after script):

```
insert into user (UserName,Password,key,mobi)  values ($UserName,$pass,$key,900000000)
```

Problem is, the password needs to be MD5, and that MD5 password must be in ALL UPPERCASE.

So could someone please give me a very basic code for doing this, including the form part?
I appreciate any help, since I'm still lost when it comes to forms and dropping info into tables... Thanks alot! :)

Comment: `strtoupper(md5($password));`?

Comment: Two potential security issues: 1. Don't use md5 for passwords -- 2. WHY are you uppercasing?...significantly less password combinations - very susceptible to brute force attacks. You should allow all possible characters and use [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Comment: I have to uppercase, because software I'm using requires the MD5 to all be uppercase. There's no reason to vote down a question, when a person who asks such a specific question obviously has their reasons.

Comment: `strtoupper(hash($pw))` is fine, I thought you meant `hash(strtoupper($pw))`

Comment: Considering the fact I don't know those functions, I'll try to re-word it: I want the password to be converted to MD5. I then want the MD5 converted to be all uppercase letters.

Could you please help answer this? lol

Comment: Copy paste Madara's answer.
Jordan's using hash() as a psudo code for md5();

And.. to make a form is exactly the same as you do any other form in html..

Comment: An HTML form doesn't really have anything to do with this. You can use a form to pass values to your PHP script (just Google if you don't know how to do this; there are TONS of good examples), but any interaction with your database will be done entirely in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it in the MySQL query if you want:

```
INSERT INTO user (UserName,Password,key,mobi)
VALUES ($UserName,UPPER(MD5($pass)),$key,900000000)
```

In PHP instead, just use this as your query, assuming you have properly sanitized the variables from the form:

```
"INSERT INTO user (UserName,Password,key,mobi)
VALUES ('$UserName','".strtoupper(md5($pass))."','$key',900000000)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please tell me how to do it with a form? That's half of where I'm lost, lol!

Comment: I'd advise against doing it in the query; the query sent across to your database would show the password in plaintext. The second solution is alright, but I'd use PDO to make a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks, But I've still to know how to set the form to actually set the values of the $username variable, and such.

Comment: Not trying to be purposely unhelpful, but it would take someone longer to type up an example of using an HTML form with PHP than it would take you to look it up. This is a very basic thing - just check out any of these tutorials: http://www.google.com/#q=html+forms+with+php

Comment: Thanks... btw sgroves, I think I know you from another site... lol